# cannot open downloaded file from base64 string Gmail API

Tags: php, base64, gmail-api, readfile

I am downloading an attachment using a base64 string from Gmail API.  When I open the downloaded file using Windows, I see the error `'We can't open this file'`.  I have checked the headers from `$data` array and they are correct, I have also checked the size of the file downloaded and this is also the correct size.

I download the file using the below:

```
$data = $json['data'];

$data = strtr($data, array('-' => '+', '_' => '/'));

$image = base64_decode($data);

header('Content-Type: image/jpg; name="crop-1.jpg"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="crop-1.jpg"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
header('X-Attachment-Id: f_j1bj7er60');

readfile($image);

// I have also tried
echo $image;
```

The `$image` string is valid because if I use the below  the image displays correctly:

```
echo "<div>
       <img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64, $image\" />
      </div>";
```

How do I fix the file download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$data** variable is **base64_encode** resource.

```
<?php
$decoded = base64_decode($data);
$file = 'download_file.jpg';
file_put_contents($file, $decoded);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    unlink($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

*Sorry, my english bad*

The following information may be helpful.

Detect MIME Content-type for a file

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

or alternative function.

class file info https://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php

```
function _mime_content_type($filename) {
    $result = new finfo();

    if (is_resource($result) === true) {
        return $result->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    }

    return false;
}
```

file_get_contents() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

base64_encode() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

example code.

```
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```

Comment: I can already display the image, the problem is with downloading the image,  after its downloaded and I open the file I see 'We can't open this file'